# Need regex which starts with 784 and having length of 15 numbers only

Tags: regex

I need a regex which needs to fulfill following requirements

1. Numbers Only
2. Length of 15 numbers exactly
3. Starts with 784

I have created a regex **^784(0-9){15}** but may be there is something wrong with this because its not matching my input **"784100100100100"**

Tested on following websites:

http://www.freeformatter.com/regex-tester.html

http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Comment: 15 digits all in all, or `784` + 15 digits?

Comment: Try `^784[0-9]{12}$`, or `^784\d{12}$`

Comment: 15 digits all in all

Comment: @Tushar, your edit is correct. Undelete the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. To match numbers from `0` to `9` use it in character class as range. `(0-9)` will match `0-9` and add it in capturing group.
2. Change `{15}` to `{12}` as only fifteen digits are to be allowed and `784` is already given at the start.
3. Add ends-with anchor `$` to not allow anyting after the numbers.

Change

```
^784(0-9){15}
```

To

```
^784[0-9]{12}$
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/zP9fK0/1)

```css
input:valid {
  color: green;
}
input:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input pattern="784[0-9]{12}" value="784" />
```

Comment: Thanx alot @Tushar 
Sorry I have no idea about regex :p